# what happens when their is a bicoin algorithm half?

Tags: algorithms

I saw in an article something about a bitcoin algorithm half in 2020, what exactly is this, I have tried looking this up but I couldn't find anything that told me what it was only [this](https://bitcoinblockhalf.com/).